# Adding words to result list which appear on the second, fourth, sixth etc times in original list

Tags: java

The main point of this exercise is to count the occurrence of words in the list and add words that appear in the list on the second, foutŕth, sixth etc times and add those to the result list. So far I'm just able to count the occurrence of each word and only add words, which count is even, to the result list. As an example, if I loop through a list, first time getting "a" count = 1, second time "a" count = 2 and adding "a" to list, third time getting "a", count = 3 and fourth time "a" count = 4 and adding "a" to list and result would be ["a", "a"]

```
public static List<String> onlyEvenWordsList(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordsWithCount = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> onlyEvenWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        Integer count = wordsWithCount.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        wordsWithCount.put(word, count + 1);
        //System.out.println(wordsWithCount);
            
        }
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: wordsWithCount.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue() % 2 == 0){
            onlyEvenWords.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    return onlyEvenWords;
}
```

So, for example, the given input and needed output:

```
System.out.println(onlyEvenWordsList(Arrays.asList("eggs", "bacon", "SPAM", "ham", "SPAM", "SPAM"))); // [SPAM]
System.out.println(onlyEvenWordsList(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c", "a"))); // [a, b, c, a]
System.out.println(onlyEvenWordsList(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "a"))); // [a]
```

Comment: So what happens when you run your program? Incorrect output or an error?

Comment: Sorry but I am finding  it hard, can you re-phrase this question?